# I'm working on MVC 4 , when I try to insert data into user table an error occurs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 4, and when I try to insert data into user table an error occurs:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(PHARMACY.Models.User)' has some invalid arguments    E:\Testing\PHARMACY\PHARMACY\Controllers\AdminController.cs 56  21  PHARMACY

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateUser(Createuser cu)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (UserDB db = new UserDB())
            {
                db.users.Add(cu);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                cu = null;
                ViewBag.Message = "User Added Sucessfully";
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        { 
        }
}
```

This is my model

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }     
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string User_Type { get; set; }
    public string Login_Status { get; set; }
}

public class Createuser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Fullname", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string Full_Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select User type", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "User Type")]
    public string User_Type { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Login Status", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Login Status")]
    public string Login_Status { get; set; }
}

public class UserDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `db.users.Add()` method accepts a `User`, yet you pass it a `CreateUser`. That won't work.

You need to map the `CreateUser` to a `User`:

```
var user = new User
{
    Full_Name = cu.Full_Name,
    ...
}

db.users.Add(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not put a CreateUser into a table that expects a User. They might have the same properties etc. put they are not the same type, so no dice.

No need to "convert" your CreateUser into a User object, and store that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a `Createuser` type to a `User` type.

You are doing `db.users.Add(cu);` when `cu` is of type `Createuser`. You'll need to do a transformation from `Createuser` to `User` first.